# Textbook recommendation: Metric Geometry

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I’m currently reading Burago, Burago, Ivanov’s book *A Course in Metric Geometry*. I’m really enjoying it so far - what would be a good continuation to the book once I’m done?

Comment: Hi! What's your background?

Comment: Hi! I’ve studied analysis from Stein and Shakarchi book 3 and 4. Also some riemannian geometry from Lee and a bit of geometric measure theory. I’ve also read Clara Loh’s book on geometric group theory, which seems to be quite related to this topic.

Comment: That’s all of the relevant background I can think of for now..

Comment: see https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08539.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have been reading Loh's book, I recommend you take a look at *Metric spaces of non-positive curvature* by M. Bridson and A. Häfliger.

See also [An invitation to Alexandrov geometry: CAT(0) spaces](https://anton-petrunin.github.io/invitation/) by S. Alexander, V. Kapovitch and A. Petrunin, or its [older version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03483/).

Comment: Looks good, thanks!

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Hi, I took a look to your notes and I think they are a very good introduction. Since they were already mentioned in another comment, I have added them to my answer to make them easier to find.

Comment: The book mentioned by Igor Belegradek is a bigger project, so far only draft is available; it is more like reference source (not an introduction).

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I see, it is good to know!

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Why is the Springer version much shorter than the one on Arxiv ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon I think your are talking about different books both versions of "Invitation"  https://anton-petrunin.github.io/invitation/ are nearly identical and the big book https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08539 is not finished.